# How to redirect IIS logs to windows event logs in windows 7

Tags: windows, iis-7.5, windows-event-log

I am using windows 7 OS with IIS 7.5 I need to redirect the IIS log files to the Windows Event Log. In IIS 8.5 there is an option to perform the above operation, but I require that to be done in IIS 7.5

Is there any option in IIS7.5 to redirect the log files to Windows event logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in any IIS release before 8.5.

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/logging-to-etw-in-iis-85